# How to get rid of this annoying effect in jquery?

Tags: jquery, firefox, mozilla, transition

I have developed a site http://www.ssitfriends.com/ and i used jquery fancy transitions....
when i saw my sight in firefox my banner moves to right causing an annoying effect..... How to get rid of this?

**Edit:On initial page load it doesnt work when i pressed F5 jquery effect is working and it is shaky.....**

Comment: The banner on the top of the site?  I'm looking at it in Firefox 3.6.3, and it looks good to me... but perhaps I'm looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: @Edgar My banner swaps 5 images..it is shaky during the swap...

Comment: @Edgar On initial page load it is not working refresh that page it will shake during the image swap

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. Are you on a very slow internet connection? Perhaps you need to [preload the images](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript)?

Comment: @Eli  On initial page load it is not working refresh that page it will shake during the image swap

Comment: Hmm... I'm not seeing the refresh shake.  Very odd... are you using FF 3.6, or an older one?

Comment: @Edgar NO no on initial page load jquery swap effect is not working i dont know why??? another thing is after refreshing that page swap effect is working but it is shaky????did u get it...am using FF 3.5.1